# Flutter flow red screen

Tags: android, flutter, flutterflow

I recently made an application in FlutterFlow, but when I integrated with firebase and ran the project, it generated an unexpected error, the screen turned red

I would like to know if by paying for the flutter flow plan I will be able to have more hits to resolve this error and I would like to know if anyone has gone through this and knows how to solve it

[image]

Comment: I experience the same problem myself but deploying the application to Testflight works for me. Reviewing the FlutterFlow forum I see that several people have experiences the same issue and an GitHub Issue has been created (https://github.com/FlutterFlow/flutterflow-issues/issues/1037) so I would follow that issue and hope that the FlutterFlow team will review it as soon as possible.